# Ruby/Rails/Rspec - ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

OK, here's my rspec code ...

```
        before(:each) do
            @attr = { :greeting => "Lorem ipsum", :recipient => @recipient }
        end

        it "should redirect to the home page" do
            puts "spec: @attr = #{@attr}"
            puts "spec: recipient = #{@attr[:recipient]}"
            post :create, :card => @attr
            response.should redirect_to(root_path)
        end
```

Now the output from this is:

```
spec: @attr = {:greeting=>"Lorem ipsum", :recipient=>#<User id: 2, first_name: "Example", last_name: "User", email: "recipient@example.com", created_at: "2011-12-22 04:01:02", updated_at: "2011-12-22 04:01:02", encrypted_password: "2d1323ad5eb21fb5ae5e87dfa78a63b521c56833189cc049ee2...", salt: "2679fcc29a30e939541cb98cb65d1d508035fea0eff1136037a...", admin: false>}
spec: recipient = #<User:0xac5d80c>
```

So we can see that recipient is a User.

On the controller side, we see have ...

```
def create
    puts "create: Params = #{params}"
    @card = current_user.sent_cards.build(params[:card])
    if @card.save
        flash[:success] = "Card created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'pages/home'
    end
end
```

With a display of ...

```
create: Params = {"card"=>{"greeting"=>"Lorem ipsum", "recipient"=>"2"}, "controller"=>"cards", "action"=>"create"}
```

and I see an error of ...

```
1) CardsController POST 'create' success should create a card
   Failure/Error: post :create, :card => @attr
   ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
     User(#90303150) expected, got String(#76171330)
   # ./app/controllers/cards_controller.rb:7:in `create'
   # ./spec/controllers/cards_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/controllers/cards_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So ... how did the User object get changed into its id as a string? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an entire object as a parameter. Rails replaces the object with its id if it has one or else passes a string representation of the object i.e. `#<User:0xac5d80c>` for your case if it doesn't find the id.

So for your case, you should rename the :recipient parameter to :recipient_id. Then

```
@card = current_user.sent_cards.build(params[:card])
```

will create your card with the associated recipient as we have passed in the recipient_id.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I changed my before to look like ...

    before(:each) do
        attr = { :greeting => "Lorem ipsum", :recipient_id => recipient.id }
    end

Is that what you meant? That got rid of the error I was seeing, but now the ...

    card = current_user.sent_cards.build(params[:card])

(card, attr, and recipient_id should have the "at" sign in front) is showing that the recipient_id is nil in the created card. Do I need to get the User from the recipient_id before I build the card? Something else?

Comment: Figured it out. Different problem. Had to get the recipient using find_by_id.

Thanks again.