# FactoryGirl, Paperclip, Rspec undefined upload method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, factory-bot

I followed this repo, [rails-multimodel-upload-demo](https://github.com/goooseman/rails-multimodel-upload-demo), from github on how to have multiple uploads using paperclip and rails. I am currently trying to make my specs pass, but there are four errors atm.

```
Failures:

  1) Cars Cars#show page navigation is the car details nav 
     Failure/Error: before { visit car_path(car) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:77:in `block in _app_views_cars_show_html_haml___4520108654775620781_2201394220'
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:71:in `each'
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:71:in `_app_views_cars_show_html_haml___4520108654775620781_2201394220'
     # ./spec/requests/cars_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Cars Cars#show page navigation is the car details nav 
     Failure/Error: before { visit car_path(car) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:77:in `block in _app_views_cars_show_html_haml___4520108654775620781_2201394220'
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:71:in `each'
     # ./app/views/cars/show.html.haml:71:in `_app_views_cars_show_html_haml___4520108654775620781_2201394220'
     # ./spec/requests/cars_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Cars /inventory navigation is the normal main nav 
     Failure/Error: before { visit inventory_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/cars/index.html.haml:22:in `block in _app_views_cars_index_html_haml___2242562919032452782_2174180500'
     # ./app/views/cars/index.html.haml:16:in `_app_views_cars_index_html_haml___2242562919032452782_2174180500'
     # ./spec/requests/cars_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Cars /inventory navigation is the normal main nav 
     Failure/Error: before { visit inventory_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/cars/index.html.haml:22:in `block in _app_views_cars_index_html_haml___2242562919032452782_2174180500'
     # ./app/views/cars/index.html.haml:16:in `_app_views_cars_index_html_haml___2242562919032452782_2174180500'
     # ./spec/requests/cars_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.58 seconds
132 examples, 4 failures
```

cars_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'                                    

describe "Cars" do                                       
  describe "/inventory" do                               
    before { visit inventory_path }                      
    subject { page }                                     

    describe "navigation" do                             
      describe "is the normal main nav" do               
        it { should have_selector("#main-nav") }         
        it { should_not have_selector("#car-nav") }      
      end                                                
    end                                                  
  end                                                    

  describe "Cars#show page" do                           
    let(:car) { FactoryGirl.create(:car) }               
    before { visit car_path(car) }                       
    subject { page }                                     

    describe "navigation" do                             
      describe "is the car details nav" do               
        it { should have_selector("#car-nav") }          
        it { should_not have_selector("#main-nav") }     
      end                                                
    end                                                  
  end                                                    
end
```

show.html.haml

```
%section#enquire                                         
  = link_to contact_path(subject: "Enquiry: #{@car.year}\
 #{@car.make} #{@car.model}", anchor: 'send-us-a-message\
'), class: 'button' do                                   
    Enquire                                              
    %br                                                  
    %span                                                
      for more details                                   
%section#view-more                                       
  .row                                                   
    .small-12.small-centered.columns                     
      %h1                                                
        View More                                        
      %ul.small-block-grid-1.medium-block-grid-3         
        - @cars.each do |car|                            
          %li                                            
            %p                                           
              = car.year                                 
              = car.make                                 
              = car.model                                
            = link_to image_tag(car.uploads.first.upload.url), car
```

Here you can see `car.uploads.first.upload.url`, so I think this is where the error is occurring.

I have tried to follow [How Do I Use Factory Girl To Generate A Paperclip Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294824/how-do-i-use-factory-girl-to-generate-a-paperclip-attachment) without success. The models are similar to the question however.

The error mentions that there there is a nil class, so the upload wasn't being made in the factory. Even when I followed the previous' questions' answers, I didn't get it to work.

cars_controller.rb

```
  def show                                               
    @cars = Car.without_car(@car).shuffle[0...3]         
    @previous = @car.id == 1 ? Car.last : Car.find( @car\
.id - 1 )                                                
    @next = @car == Car.last ? Car.first : Car.find( @ca\
r.id + 1 )                                               
    @uploads = @car.uploads                              
    @bodyid = 'car-details'                              
  end
```

After making some changes to my factories

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess                                                                                 

FactoryGirl.define do                                                                                               
  factory :car do                                                                                                   
    make "MyString"                                                                                                 
    model "MyString"                                                                                                
    year 1                                                                                                          
    seats 1                                                                                                         
    transmission "MyString"                                                                                         
    drive "MyString"                                                                                                
    interior "MyString"                                                                                             
    exterior "MyString"                                                                                             
    uploads { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'photos', 'test.jpg'), 'image/jpg') }                     
  end                                                                                                               
end
```

I get more errors

```
Failure/Error: let(:car) { FactoryGirl.create(:car) }
     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Upload(#2223442800) expected, got String(#2164378420)
```

from reading about `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`, the object is being passed into the car variable. [Ruby/Rails/Rspec - ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599359/ruby-rails-rspec-activerecordassociationtypemismatch) I'm not sure how this exactly relates, but I'm looking into it.

Comment: where is your @cars instance,means from where u are getting it...?

Comment: If `car.uploads` returns an empty array then `.first` will become `nil`. So you should check your fixtures or make the view work when no uploads exists. This comment is based on the last row in youre haml file

Comment: @RahulSingh from the cars_controller. Updated question with the controller#show

Comment: @aross my thoughts exactly. I tried using a fixture to fix it, without success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294824/how-do-i-use-factory-girl-to-generate-a-paperclip-attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a previous and next links feature when my previous failing specs passed. This is the answer that solved it [RSpec and Factory for testing next, prev records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300685/rspec-and-factory-for-testing-next-prev-records/14301109#14301109)

The reason `upload` was not defined was because the `let(:user)` does not actually write a record for `:user`. Once I added `let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` everything worked